# Flutter StreamBuilder connectionState problem with firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got this code below, the problem I'm facing here is that connectionState seems to always show "false" when the page is loading at least.
I have "myValue" value on firestore, under the subCollection 'subItem' of 'items' and some items have this subCollection already created and hasData but some don't.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return StreamBuilder(
   stream:Firestore.instance
          .collection('other')
          .document(documentID)
          .snapshots(),
   builder: (context, streamSnapshot1) {


   return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('items')
          .document(documentID)
          .collection('subItems')
          .document(userUID)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, streamSnapshot2) {
                  return _detailPage(context, streamSnapshot2)
                       });
              }
        });
    }

Widget _detailPage(context, streamSnapshot1, streamSnapshot2) {
       var myValue = (streamSnapshot2.connectionState != true) ? 1
                    : (streamSnapshot2.hasData) ? streamSnapshot2.data['myValue']: 2;

          print(myValue);

           return Scaffold(etc)
                 }
```

In this case, 'myValue' always prints '1'. Whether it has value on firestore or not. when I print connectionState, it shows 'connectionState.waiting' for a while and then is changed to 'connectionState.active'. 'connectionState.waiting' shown at first is known behavior of firestore stream, but even after it is changed to active, it still considers 'streamSnapshot2.connectionState != true' and return '1'. Should it be 'connectionState.done' to be considered as 'streamSnapshot2.connectionState == true'? But it never changes to "connectionStat.done" though.

When I tried without 'connectionState' and only checked with hasData,

```
var myValue = (streamSnapshot2.hasData) ? streamSnapshot2.data['myValue']: 2;
```

it is ok and shows the right value of 'myValue' stored on firestore, when the Item already have 'subItems' subCollection and datas in it. But in this case, the app breaks in the Item where it doesn't have 'subItem' subCollection created yet. With the error message below.

```
error: The method '[]' was called on null.
```

it's because 'streamSnapshot.data' is yet null. I couldn't understand this too because although there is no data and thus it is null, it passed through (streamSnapshot2.hasData == true) condition.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connectionState is never equal to true because it's simply not a boolean value.
As you noticed, it's an ConnectionState enum value, so if you want to check a connectionState of AsyncSnapshot, you have to compare it to a ConnectionsState enum value. So for example if you want to know whether stream has loaded you need to check if state is different than waiting: (you have observed it by yourself with print statements)

```
if(streamSnapshot1.connectionState
 != ConnectionState.waiting) {
//stream has loaded some first values 
}
```